# DialogFragment и Обычные Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

Проблема заключается в том что когда я вызываю `fragment` и делаю `replace` `commit` на него и после этого я вызываю `DialogFragment` с тэгом, то в последствии я не могу найти этот `DialogFragment` по тэгу и удалить его.Есть два варианта, первый это при котором диалог не удаляется через промежуток времени и второй вариант в котором все работает отлично (но я не могу быть уверен на 100% правильное ли это решение проблемы).

**I Вариант**
**Activity**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        loginFragment=LoginFragment.newInstance();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_left,R.animator.slide_right);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_content,loginFragment,);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        startServer(WebSocketListener.TYPE_CONNECT);
        Log.i(TAG,"commit");



    }
```

Создается DialogFragment в методе `startServer` в котором вызывается еще один метод `createServerConnectionDialog`

**createServerConnectionDialog в Activity**

```
 @Override
    public void createServerConnectionDialog() {
        ServerConnectionDialog serverConnectionDialog=ServerConnectionDialog.newInstance(getResources().getString(R.string.string_connect));
        serverConnectionDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),ServerConnectionDialog.class.getSimpleName());
    }
```

**И чуть позже он должен удаляться методом deleteServerConnectionDialog в Activity**

```
 @Override
    public void deleteServerConnectionDialog() {
            ServerConnectionDialog serverConnectionDialog=(ServerConnectionDialog) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ServerConnectionDialog.class.getSimpleName());
            if (serverConnectionDialog != null) {
            serverConnectionDialog.dismiss();
            }
    }
```

Диалог не удаляется  потому что `serverConnectionDialog = null`

**II Вариант**

**Activity**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        loginFragment=LoginFragment.newInstance();
        loginFragment.setOnCreate(new LoginFragment.OnCreate() {
            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");
                loginFragment.setOnCreate(null);
                startServer(WebSocketListener.TYPE_CONNECT);

            }
        });
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_left,R.animator.slide_right);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_content,loginFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();




    }
```

`createServerConnectionDialog`  и `deleteServerConnectionDialog` идентичны I варианту

**LoginFragment**

```
 public interface OnCreate{
        public void onCreate();
    }



    public void setOnCreate(OnCreate onCreate) {
        this.onCreate = onCreate;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(onCreate!=null) {
            onCreate.onCreate();
        }
    }
```

Все работает отлично...

**Цель:** Узнать почему так происходит и правильное ли решение я нашел этой проблеме, если нет то я бы хотел увидеть правильное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Использую**

```
fragmentTransaction.commitNow();
```